# How to install ioreg?

Tags: macos, terminal, installation

ioreg was on my system, I use to run a program iStats and everything worked fine. Now for some reason when I run iStats it throws an error that ioreg cannot be found. If I run:

```
which ioreg
ioreg not found
```

But if I go to ***/usr/sbin*** ioreg is there. No other programs have seem to broken, I don't have any clue why it wouldn't be able to find it.
I would like to just reinstall it or get it working again.

Comment: I don't think that should be tagged as `linux`, since Linux doesn't even have this utility.

Comment: I'll fix it, I didn't know, so is it just a Mac specific program? Thanks

Comment: Yes, [as far as I know](https://lists.debian.org/debian-powerpc/2005/09/msg00545.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your `PATH` variables are broken.

Try running this in Terminal, it will reset your defaults `PATH`s:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

Then run `which ioreg` again.